# Why is app pool inside IIS 10 crashing during a scheduled recycling event?

Tags: iis

I have a .NET application running on Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10. This application is configured with its own application pool. There are other applications hosted on the same server each with its own application pool. Each application pool is configured to recycle daily on a staggered interval starting at 12:00 AM.

Randomly some of these application pools are crashing while recycling and I have no idea what is contributing to these crashes. If I go and recycle them again, they come back up fine.

The error that appears repeatedly around this crash is something like

> "A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '11268'
>   serving application pool 'MyApp' reported a listener channel failure"

Here are the events from event vrw that occurred when one such app pool crashed associated with the app called MyApp.

1. A worker process with process id of '13276' serving application pool 'MyApp' has requested a recycle because it reached its scheduled recycle time.

   ```
   <Event>   
     <System>
        <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-WAS" Guid="{524B5D04-133C-4A62-8362-64E8EDB9CE40}" EventSourceName="WAS" /> 
        <EventID Qualifiers="16384">5076</EventID>
        <Version>0</Version>
        <Level>4</Level>
        <Task>0</Task>
        <Opcode>0</Opcode>
        <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-11-16T06:05:02.544043500Z" />   
        <EventRecordID>112746</EventRecordID>
        <Correlation />
        <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
        <Channel>System</Channel>
        <Computer>XYZP00953</Computer>
        <Security />
      </System>
      <EventData>
        <Data Name="ProcessID">13276</Data>
        <Data Name="AppPoolID">MyApp</Data>
        <Binary />
      </EventData>
   </Event>
   ```

*Some how the xml I am posting is not getting formatted correctly. I will edit again to see if it gets fixed.*

2. A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '11268' serving application pool 'MyApp' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

   5139
     0
     3
     0
     0
     0x80000000000000
     
     112747
     
     
     System
     XYZP00953
     
     
     
     MyApp
     11268
     0
     http
     0615F6FF
3. A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '10292' serving application pool 'MyApp' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

   5139
     0
     3
     0
     0
     0x80000000000000
     
     112748
     
     
     System
     XYZP00953
     
     
     
     MyApp
     10292
     0
     http
     0615F6FF
4. A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '9584' serving application pool 'MyApp' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

   5139
     0
     3
     0
     0
     0x80000000000000
     
     112749
     
     
     System
     XYZP00953
     
     
     
     MyApp
     9584
     0
     http
     0615F6FF
5. A worker process '13900' serving application pool 'MyApp' failed to start a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.

   5137
   0
   3
   0
   0
   0x80000000000000

   112751


   System
   XYZP00953



   MyApp
   13900
   0
   http
   B4050780
6. A worker process '4320' serving application pool 'MyApp' failed to start a listener channel for protocol 'http' in the allotted time.  The data field contains the error number.

   5137
   0
   3
   0
   0
   0x80000000000000

   112755


   System
   XYZP00953



   MyApp
   4320
   0
   http
   B4050780
7. Application pool 'MyApp' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

   5002
   0
   2
   0
   0
   0x80000000000000

   112756


   System
   XYZP00953



   MyApp

Comment: What is the identity for the app pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit. A third party iis module was crashing and it was taking down MyApp pool along with it. Working with the vendor on it.

Comment: Where would the information that an IIS module crashed be located?